# Solspace Tag entries page not displaying list

Tags: solspace, solspace-tag

I've reached out to SolSpace for help with this, but they aren't proving to be very smart. Perhaps the SE community can come to the rescue.

I am trying to display a list of my entries associated with a certain tag, but so far this only yields a blank page. I know my tags are working correctly because they are automatically showing up on the categories left-hand list and below the articles.

Code for the by_tag EE template.

```
        {exp:tag:entries channel="blog_entry"}
        <div class="entry-tease" style="width:100%;float:left;clear:both;">
            <img src="{blog_image}" class="teaser-image">
            <h2><a href="{url_title_path='blog/entry'}" title="{title}">{title}</a></h2>
            {exp:trunchtml chars="450" inline="..."}
                {entry_text}
            {/exp:trunchtml}
            <a href="{url_title_path='blog/entry'}" title="Read more" class="read-button">Read more</a>
        </div>
        {/exp:tag:entries}
```

Any thoughts why this isn't working? SolSpace said it should with the exp:tag:entries opening and closing blocks, but again, nothing. I know there's 2 articles tagged with news as well. I do have Structure installed, but I don't see why it would be causing interference.

Comment: When you say "bank page", do you mean a completely white screen? This would indicate an error in processing possibly. If you strip out the contents between the tag pair to simply `{title}`, does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

https://solspace.com/docs/tag/tags/#tag_group_name

Set your tag_group_name parameter to {segment_4}.

```
{exp:tag:entries channel="blog_entry" tag_group_name="{segment_4}"}
    ...
{/exp:tag:entries}
```

Comment: just tried it. Didn't work either :(

Comment: Well, apparently adding your tag_group_name and removing their /tag/ taxonomy from the url did the trick. Thanks for your help!